# Template Class to differentiate object type?

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

Can I use C++ template classes to differentiate object types? Or what should I use?

Eg. I have a class `Synonym` and it can be of type `Statement, Procedure, etc` for example. I have functions that accepts these synonyms and evaluates them depending on its type. So I was thinking it will be nice if I can do something like:

```
enum Types { Statement, Procedure, Variable, ... };

template <typename Types>
class Synonym { ... }

void evaluate(Synonym<Statement> s, Synonym<Variable> v) { do something }
              ^ so that I can do this ... instead of checking the type in function like: 

void evaluate(Synonym s, Synonym v) {
    assert(s.type == Statement);
    assert(v.type == Variable);

    // also would like to eliminate things like: (if possible)
    switch(s.type) {
        case XXX: doSomething ... 
        case YYY: doAnotherThing ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get it, what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: And you can always overload function parameters so yeah the first evaluate should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function template and then specialize on that template

```
template<typename Type>
void evaluate (Type t) {}

template<>
void evaluate<Statement>( Statement s)
{}
```

This way, when you pass a `Statement` it will pick that overload, and you can do different behaviors depending on type.

Answer (score 0):

I think using a variant and visitor pattern would be suited. Have a look at Boost.Variant here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/variant.html, the last example (also below but expanded) shows a visitor implementation. There are also other variant and visitor implementations. std::any and loki are also options. I personally like loki but that is probably just because I'm a huge fan of Alexandrescu.

```
#include "boost/variant.hpp"
#include <iostream>

class ToLengthVisitor : public boost::static_visitor<int>
{
public:
    int operator()(int i) const
    {
        return i;
    }

    int operator()(const std::string & str) const
    {
        return str.length();
    }

    int operator()(const char * str) const
    {
        const char * temp = str;
        while(*temp != '\0') temp++;
        return temp-str;
    }
};

int main()
{
    typedef boost::variant< int, std::string, const char * > MyVariant;
    MyVariant u(std::string("hello world"));
    std::cout << u; // output: hello world

    MyVariant cu(boost::get<std::string>(u).c_str());

    int result = boost::apply_visitor( ToLengthVisitor(), u );
    std::cout << result; // output: 11 (i.e., length of "hello world")
    result = boost::apply_visitor( ToLengthVisitor(), cu );
    std::cout << result; // output: 11 (i.e., length of "hello world")
}
```